# ¿Cómo leer un fichero de texto en C y crear un arreglo de structuras?

Tags: array, c, estructuras-de-datos

No se bien como funciona en C el uso de la memoria. Queria que cuando le diera a la opción 1, se me solicitara el nombre de un fichero y del fichero creara un arreglo de pacientes, pero no controlo con este lenguaje.

Cuanto intento ejecutar el programa, el fichero lo abre de manera correcta pero no se sacar de ahí los valores para las variables de la estructura `pacientes`.

*Dar de alta uno o varios nuevo(s) paciente(s) en el sistema.*

Inicialmente no existirán pacientes registrados. El programa solicitará el nombre del fichero de  texto que  contiene la información del nuevo(s) pacientes(s).

Se deberá mostrar un mensaje indicando si se ha dado de alta el o los pacientes(s) con éxito o si ha habido  algún  error.

Se deja a criterio del alumno definir el formato  de este fichero. Un posible ejemplo de fichero a leer podría ser el siguiente

```
23452369P
Pepe LopezMartinez
C/Gran Vía, 33
669784858
```

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Variables

#define TOTAL_PACIENTES 1000
#define ID 50
#define MAX_FILE 80

//structuras

struct paciente {
        char dni[ID];
        char nombre;
        char apellidos;
        int telefono;
        char direccion;
        char fechaNacimiento;
        //los grupos poblacionales pueden ser 6
        int grupoPoblacional;
        //como mucho un pociente podra meterse 3 vacunas
        int vacunas;
};


void inicializar (struct paciente pacientes[TOTAL_PACIENTES])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_PACIENTES; i++)
        pacientes[i].dni[0] = '\0';
}

int coger_datos_paciente(char dni[ID])
{
    //
    FILE *fp;
    int error = 0;
    char fichero[MAX_FILE];
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Introduce el nombre del fichero: ");
    gets(fichero);

    if ((fp = fopen(fichero,"r")) != NULL)
    {
        //fichero abierto correctamente
        fgets(dni,ID,fp);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error al abrir el fichero.\n");
        error = 1;
    }
    return error;

}

int main()
{
    int contador_pacientes = 0;
    int error = 0;

    struct paciente pacientes[TOTAL_PACIENTES];
    char identificador_paciente[ID];
    inicializar(pacientes);


    char opt;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("\n**GESTION HOPISTAL FALSE COVID**\n\n");
        printf("1.- Dar   de   alta   uno o   varios nuevo/s pacientes/s en   el   sistema\n");
        printf("2.- Dar de baja uno o varios pacientes existente dado su DNI\n");
        printf("3.- Dar  de alta una o  varias nuevas  inoculaciones\n");
        printf("4.- Eliminar  una o  varias inoculaciones\n");
        printf("5.- Guardar  estado  del  programa\n");
        printf("6.- Cargar estado de fichero\n");
        printf("7.- Listar datos del  proceso  de  vacunación\n");
        printf("8.- Salir");
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\nOpcion: ");scanf("%c", &opt);
        switch (opt)
        {
        case '1':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 1");
            //Alta paciente.
            error = coger_datos_paciente(identificador_paciente);
            if (!error)
            {
                contador_pacientes = 0;
                while((pacientes[contador_pacientes].dni[0] != '\0') && (contador_pacientes < TOTAL_PACIENTES)) contador_pacientes++;
                if (contador_pacientes < TOTAL_PACIENTES){
                    printf("algo es algo");
                    printf(pacientes[contador_pacientes].dni[0]);
                    //pacientes[contador_pacientes] = alta_paciente(identificador_polilinea);
            }
                else
                    printf("BBDD esta llena.\n");
            }
            else
                printf("Error en la insercion.\n");

            break;
        case '2':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 2");
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 3");
            break;
        case '4':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 4");
            break;
        case '5':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 5");
            break;
        case '6':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 6");
            break;
        case '7':
            printf("Le diste a la opcion 7");
            break;
        case '8':
            return 0;
        default :
            printf("ERROR");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como leer un archivo txt y cargar su contenido en un array de estructura de datos, con la diferencia de que este array no es de tamaño estatico, sino que el tamaño es definido en tiempo de ejecucion mediante el conteo de las lineas de texto que contiene el archivo, para posteriormente reservar memoria con malloc, en cuanto a la lectura del archivo es posible siempre y cuando los registros del archivo leido esten guardados de la siguiente forma:
`11111111,manuel,gutierrez_lopez,222222222,avenida_la_paz_100,8/10/1995,333,2 11111111,manuel,gutierrez_lopez,222222222,avenida_la_paz_100,8/10/1995,333,2 11111111,manuel,gutierrez_lopez,222222222,avenida_la_paz_100,8/10/1995,333,2`

si el formato es distinto a lo mostrado antes, entonces no funcionaria.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct paciente{
    char dni[20];
    char nombre[20];
    char apellidos[30];
    int telefono;
    char direccion[30];
    char fechaNacimiento[20];
    int grupoPoblacional;
    int vacunas;
};

//se redefine la estructura 'struct paciente' por 'Paciente' para simplificar su referencia
typedef struct paciente Paciente;

//se llena la variable paciente copiando campo por campo luego retorna la variable paciente
Paciente copiar(char leer[]){
    Paciente paciente;
    
    //strtok lee un string hasta encontrar el delimitador especificado (la coma), solo la primera llamada se le pasa el array 'leer'
    strcpy(paciente.dni,strtok(leer,","));
    //las siguientes llamadas a strtok deben ser con NULL
    strcpy(paciente.nombre,strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(paciente.apellidos,strtok(NULL,","));
    //atoi convierte un string a int
    paciente.telefono = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(paciente.direccion,strtok(NULL,","));
    strcpy(paciente.fechaNacimiento,strtok(NULL,","));
    paciente.grupoPoblacional = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
    paciente.vacunas = atoi(strtok(NULL,","));
    
    //de esta manera se obtienen los valores de cada campo de la variable paciente y se retorna para que se guarde en cada
    //elemento del array tipo Paciente
    return paciente;
}

int main(void){
    Paciente *pacientes;
    char leer[255];
    int estado, cantidad = 0, i = 0;
    
    //abre archivo en modo lectura
    FILE *archivo = fopen("pacientes2.txt","r");
    
    //se recorre el archivo para obtener cantidad de registros (lineas de texto que contiene el archivo)
    //fscanf lee una cadena de caracteres del archivo y lo copia en el array 'leer' luego salta a la siguiente linea
    //con while se verifica si ya llego al final del archivo o no
    estado = fscanf(archivo,"%s",leer);
    while(estado != EOF){
        cantidad++;
        estado = fscanf(archivo,"%s",leer);
    }
    
    //se crea array dinamico de tamanio igual a la cantidad de lineas que contiene el archivo
    pacientes = (Paciente*)malloc(sizeof(Paciente)*cantidad);
    
    //el puntero interno del archivo se vuelve a posicionar al inicio
    rewind(archivo);
    
    //se recorre otra vez el archivo pero esta vez si se copian los datos en el array con la funcion copiar
    estado = fscanf(archivo,"%s",leer);
    while(estado != EOF){
        pacientes[i++] = copiar(leer);
        estado = fscanf(archivo,"%s",leer);
    }
    
    //se cierra el archivo
    fclose(archivo);
    
    //muestra el contenido del array
    for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++){
        printf("DNI                : %s\n",pacientes[i].dni);
        printf("NOMBRE             : %s\n",pacientes[i].nombre);
        printf("APELLIDOS          : %s\n",pacientes[i].apellidos);
        printf("TELEFONO           : %d\n",pacientes[i].telefono);
        printf("DIRECCION          : %s\n",pacientes[i].direccion);
        printf("FECHA DE NACIMIENTO: %s\n",pacientes[i].fechaNacimiento);
        printf("GRUPO POBLACIONAL  : %d\n",pacientes[i].grupoPoblacional);
        printf("VACUNAS            : %d\n\n",pacientes[i].vacunas);
    }
    
    //libera memoria del array dinamico reservado por malloc
    free(pacientes);
    
    return 0;
}
```